# Cut the bottom of an image instead of the top when it doesn't fit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which constains an image with diferent srcsets. I have set the div and image width and height to 100% so that the img embrace the whole page, so it is easy to assum that depending on the device screen it will show a bigger or a lower portion of the image when it doesn't fit on the div.
I'm ok with that, but the problem is that I want the image to be showed by the top so that if the height doesn't fit the 100% of the screen height and a part of the img gets cutted it is the bottom of it, but the img starts loading by the bottom and its the top the who gets cutted.

```css
.portada {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#portadaImg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.portadaLetras {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.centerBoth {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="portada centerBoth">
  <img id="portadaImg" class="img-fluid" srcset="images/portada/portada-xl.jpg 2400w,
                  images/portada/portada-l.jpg 1200w,
                  images/portada/portada-md.jpg 992w,
                  images/portada/portada-tablet.jpg 768w,
                  images/portada/portada-mobile.jpg 458w" src="images/portada/portada-mobile.jpg" alt="Foto de portada">
  <div class="portadaLetras">
    Saint Paolo
    <p>MMXIV</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what property am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following property to the .portada class besides the ones I already had:

```
object-position: center top;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't HAVE to use a srcset, why not use a background image instead of an image tag?

It would simply be:

```
.portada{
    background: #000 url(../path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Edit**

I'm a little confused but if you are still willing to use a background image, perhaps the issue is with your Div styling.

Apply this CSS on the body tag instead...

```
body{
    background: #000 url(../path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I have to use a srcset cause other way I would need to change the media-queries to change de background image of the div and I dont want to. That's the way I was doing before I tried this way.

Comment: You may have requirements that I don't know about, but in my extensive experience... these days you don't need to worry about a bunch of different images. There is overhead with that. Just pick a nice big "optimized" image for all screens. My two cents!

Comment: Okei, thanks for the advice! However although I don't implement the srcset I still have the same problem, my big image will load from the background and the top of it will be cut since it doesn't fit on the 100% height and 100% width div. If I'm not explaining myself propertly I can edit the question and post some aclarative images

Comment: @Luiscri Add `background-position:center top;` to the code above and then it will cut off the bottom instead of the top.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke That would work if I were loading the image as a background-image, but I'm loading it as a HTML image. Is there something similar for this?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Yes there is, it is called "object-position: center top". Thank you for the advice, you gave me the clue to find out how to solve it!

Comment: @Luiscri just about to suggest that, but happy I could help! You should add that as your own answer and mark it as correct for future users :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by absolutely positioning your image inside a `div` with `overflow: hidden`.

The below image is 225px tall, but its parent div is only 160px tall, so it gets cropped from the bottom, leaving the top of the image alined with the top of its parent div.

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 378px;
  height: 160px;
}
.image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/52903/pexels-photo-52903.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=225&w=378" alt="colored pencils">
</div>
```

A more generic solution that will replicate the effect of `background-size: cover; background-position: top center` would look something like this:

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 378px; /* or whatever */
  height: 160px; /* or whatever */
}
.image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```